# System.Management v7 (WMI) not supported in web apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wmi, wmi-query

With the latest release of System.Management assembly version 7 (WMI) you cannot use the apis in Web application scenarios, a PlatformNotSupportedException is thrown with message: "is only supported Windows desktop applications"

We use the WMI in our licence validation logic to obtain machine finger print. Now, we can't do this anymore (unless we use the unsupported version 5).
What are the alternatives to WMI now? If Microsoft decides to lock down an API, they should be providing alternate solutions.

UPDATE:
Looks like using System.Management v6 (still supported) nuget works too. I think, that's because it defaults to the .net framework version of the System.Management assembly compared to System.Management v7 nuget that uses the new .net standard version of the assembly.